# QOpenGLFrameBufferObject for 3D graphics

Tags: qt, opengl, framebuffer

I am currently working on creating openGL buffers in Qt for some 3D models (cuboids of various sizes depicting buildings).

I've tried to look into some examples, but I've only found some for 2D. I tried using the same for 3D, but at best I end up with blank images when I convert my buffers to images to check.

I reached the max success (at least an image is being created) using: https://dangelog.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/using-fbos-instead-of-pbuffers-in-qt-5-2/

My current code is something like:

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObject* SBuildingEditorUtils::getFboForBuilding(Building bd)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setMajorVersion(4);
    format.setMinorVersion(3);

    QWindow window;
    window.setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
    window.setFormat(format);
    window.create();

    QOpenGLContext context;
    context.setFormat(format);
    if (!context.create())
        qFatal("Cannot create the requested OpenGL context!");
    context.makeCurrent(&window);

    // TODO: fbo size = building size
    QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat fboFormat;
    fboFormat.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
    //fboFormat.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::Depth);
    auto fbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(1500, 1500, fboFormat);
    auto res = glGetError();
    auto bindRet = fbo->bind();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glOrtho(0, 1500, 0, 1500, 0, 1500); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3d(500, 500, 500);
        glVertex3d(500, 1000, 1000);
        glVertex3d(1000, 1000, 1000);
        glVertex3d(1000, 500, 500);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    fbo->toImage().save("uniqueName.png");
    fbo->release();
    glPopMatrix();

    return fbo;
}
```

Here I've been using the image "uniqueName.png" to text my output. As you can guess most of the code here just for testing. Also, this code is part of a larger code base.

Any advice of what I might be missing. While I have some experience with Qt, I lack any formal education / training in openGL. Any help would be appreciated.

I wish to know how to get the code to work.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: I wish to know what I am doing wrong so that I may fix it.

Comment: You might want to look at a decent [OpenGL tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/).  In addition, the `Qt` documentation has [plenty of examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html).

Comment: I already did that. As for the examples, I found that most were for 2D. The 3D ones were aimed at Qt Quick [ I did try to convert it to qt code ]. Both failed to give me the desired output. The tutorial is for pure openGL. I've already skimmed through some of 'em, but my timelines discourage me from putting too much time into them.

Comment: You didn't set a projection matrix. So the coordinates  of the geometry have to be set in normalized device space, which is in range [-1.0, 1.0] for the x, y and z component. If you want to use window coordinates, the you have to set an orthographic projection by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), before `glBegin` -  e.g. `glOrtho(0,1500,0,1500,0,1500)`

Comment: I had tried that, no luck. Just a heads up, I've also tried    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glPopMatrix(); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();  
 and    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, -100, 100); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);   
    glPushMatrix();  
    glLoadIdentity();

Comment: @Bhoot Pleas read my comment carefully. When you set a projection `glOrtho(...., -100, 100)`, then the near plane is -100 and the far plane is 100. So all your geometry is clipped, because your z-coordinates are 500 and 1000, and not in the range of [-100, 100].

Comment: @Rabbit76 Oh thanks for the advice. I had also tried setting glOrtho(0,1500,0,1500,0,1500) as you had suggested. It didn't seem to help. Thanks for the observation though. I'll add it and edit my current code  to represent the same.